# sending daily summary email

Tags: php, laravel

I am writing up a cron job for daily email notification.

Here are the scenario lets say

1. **User A** gets 10 leads a day.
2. **User B** gets 5 leads a day.
3. **User C** gets 2 leads a day.

i want to send **one email to User A** having 10 leads information in it.

then **one email to User B** having 5 leads information in it.

then **one email to User C** having 2 leads information in it.

so I want to try to create a summary email having lead information in it for a particular user.

```
   foreach ($today_leads as $today_lead) {

            $data[] = [
                'user_id' => $today_lead->user_id,
                'user_fullname' => $today_lead->user_fullname,
                'user_email' => $today_lead->user_email,
                'lead_firstname' => $today_lead->first_name,
                'lead_lastname' => $today_lead->last_name,
                'lead_email' => $today_lead->email,
                'lead_phone' => $today_lead->phone,
                'lead_source' => $today_lead->source,
            ];
                
            Mail::to(data['user_email'])->send(new DailyLeadSummary($data));

        }
```

if I write my in foreach loop then I end up sending 10 emails to User A, 5 emails to User B, and so on.

Any other approach to handle this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can first group your results based on `user_email` and then send email in second loop.

```
$grouped_data = [];

foreach ($today_leads as $lead) {
     $grouped_data[$lead->user_email][] = [
                'user_id' => $lead->user_id,
                'user_fullname' => $lead->user_fullname,
                'user_email' => $lead->user_email,   // you can remove it if not required in email body anywhere
                'lead_firstname' => $lead->first_name,
                'lead_lastname' => $lead->last_name,
                'lead_email' => $lead->email,
                'lead_phone' => $lead->phone,
                'lead_source' => $lead->source,
            ];
}

foreach($grouped_data AS $user_email => $data)
{
    Mail::to($user_email)->send(new DailyLeadSummary($data));
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Looking at your implementation, you're on the right path, but you need to make some adjustments.

first of all, you need to query the user table to get users with leads on the particular day. do that like this

```php
// This will return only users who got leads today
$usersWithLeads = User::whereHas('leads', function($query) {
     // This will match all leads that was created today
     $query->where('created_at', >=, now()->toStartOfDay());
})->get();


// then you can loop over $usersWithLeads

foreach($usersWithLeads as $usersWithLead) {
     // You can then retrieve the leads gotten today via the leads relationship 
    $leads = $usersWithLead->leads()->where('created_at', now()->startOfDay());

    // Then send your mail
    Mail::to($usersWithLead)->send(new DailyLeadSummary($leads));
}
```

You can then render the leads on your mailable view however you like. But this makes sure you send only one email per user.

Also, You can modify the query to retrieve $usersWithLeads to also retrieve the daily leads like this:

```php
$usersWithLeads = User::with(['leads' => function ($query) {
    $query->where('created_at', now()->toStartOfDay());
}])->whereHas('leads', function($query) {
     // This will match all leads that was created today
     $query->where('created_at', >=, now()->toStartOfDay());
})->get();
```

Then your loop will look like:

```php
foreach($usersWithLeads as $usersWithLead) {
    // Then send your mail
    Mail::to($usersWithLead)->send(new DailyLeadSummary($usersWithLead->leads));
}
```

**Note:** the `now()` method used in the query is a `Carbon` helper method for `Carbon::now()` which gives you the current time, chaining the `->startOfDay()` method on `now()` retrieves the datetime at 0:00 (when the day started)

This Answer also assumes you have a table to hold `leads` and have declared a relationship in your `User` model like:

```php
public function leads() {
    return $this->hasMany(App\Leads::class, 'user_id', 'id');
}
```

Let me know if you need more help with this.